# Host multiple projects to same firebase project

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I have two different react apps - one admin app and another client app. The two apps share the same Firebase database and now I want to deploy both of them to Firebase hosting so that I can access them from two different URLs.

To do this I followed the following approach:

1. Type `firebase init`
2. Type `firebase deploy`

This works fine, but the issue is that when I deploy my second project it overwrites the URL for my first project.

I tried adding another project in the `firebaserc` file so that it looks like:

```
{
  "projects": {
    "default": "fire-app-9c444",
    "project1": "fire-app-9c444-admin",
    "project2": "fire-app-9c444-mobile"
  }
}
```

running `firebase use` then lists the projects as

```
* default (fire-app-9c444)
  project1 (fire-app-9c444-admin)
  project2 (fire-app-9c444-mobile)
```

But I cannot change to project1 or project2. If I write `firebase use project1` I get the following error:

> Error: Unable to use alias project1, please verify project
>   fire-app-9c444-admin exists and you have access.

Any ideas how to go about this?

Comment: I did some research and it seems this is not possible in firebase currently https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=fr#!topic/firebase-talk/Khy0dpKYB_0. Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: The reply on that thread is from Firebase staff, so that's probably all the information you need.

Comment: @user3642173 I think you chould checkout this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49812141/firebase-multiple-apps-connected-to-single-firestore?rq=1) also checkout the [firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/multisites), _You can set up one or more Firebase Hosting sites in a single Firebase project_

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. In my case my `project1` app was created with a different Google account as my `project2` app. I just added the other Google account as a maintainer in my Firebase project settings ([https://console.firebase.google.com/project/${projectName}/settings/iam](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/$%7BprojectName%7D/settings/iam)). Now I can switch projects with `firebase use ${projectName}`

With `firebase login` you can check which Google account you are currently logged in